# Report with OR filter

Tags: joined-reports

I am currently creating a joined block report in SalesForce. They both have date range filter. Example: Production start date Range next 120 days from Date1 to Date2. But I would also like to include the field where the Production Start Date is "". How can I add that to the report filter as an OR condition instead of the and. I tried the logic but I don't see the Date Range as an option.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about the "Range" control, right?

[image]

To get the OR condition on the dates you'll have to stop using it and do something like that instead:

[image]

(my example is bit stupid because Opps must have the Close Date but you get the idea)